# While link only answers are discouraged, what about this sheet?

Tags: discussion

I believe this [sheet about baggage sizes](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1xM0I9Zi3hOsn3NTfkx9RE32qXgj1e3qHxuzvXfg2_78/edit?usp=sharing) should be on the main site especially because second baggage size information is extremely scarce elsewhere. There is [no markdown to create tables](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73566/is-there-markdown-to-create-tables) so it would only be a very poor replacement if I exported it -- in Google Sheets it can be ordered etc. So what about making this link alone a self answer about published baggage sizes or some such?

Comment: If you do go ahead with either of the options suggested already then please make sure it has a prominent Updated on xxxx in the page (not relying on the date of last edit).

Comment: I will certainly _not_ do this. Yes https://donatstudios.com/CsvToMarkdownTable could generate a markdown table but it's uneditable. @Willeke's solution is tenable.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, are you the owner of the spreadsheet?

Answer (score 10):

Linking to Google Sheets is unreliable since its easy to accidentally turn off access permissions at any time in the future. Likewise its poorly indexed by search engines and can be difficult to open on mobile devices. Instead you can use [this online markdown generator](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables) to produce StackExchange-compatible tables:

```
| Airline   | URL  | Two bags? | Height | Width | Depth | Height | Width | Depth |
|-----------|------|-----------|--------|-------|-------|--------|-------|-------|
| Lufthansa | Link | n         | 55     | 40    | 23    | 40     | 30    | 10    |
| Swiss     | Link | n         | 55     | 40    | 23    | 40     | 30    | 10    |
```

See the source code of this answer for details on how to format the table so that it shows up properly.

Comment: It's impossible to see the source code of meta posts unless you have edit rights, since suggested edits don't exist on meta.

Comment: @TRiG Copy the anonymous share link, then change `/a/[answer ID]` to `/posts/[answer ID]/revisions`, and view the source from there.

Comment: Thanks, @gparyani. So, here's a clickable link: https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/posts/5008/revisions.

Comment: The problem of such code blocks is the fact that screen readers cannot read them properly

Comment: @Ferrybig its still much better than Google Sheets

Answer (score 6):

If you put just a link it will likely be closed, by the community, as link only.
But if you write a short answer and put your link in that it should stay open.

As a user I do appreciate a short description of what I will find on the page where the link leads to. In this case 'a page with this kind of information' rather than a quote would do for me.

Answer (score 3):

Table Markdown now exists.

| 7/29/2022 | Height | Width | Depth | Pay to get two bags? | Height | Width | Depth | URL |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Lufthansa | 40 | 30 | 10 | n | 55 | 40 | 23 | https://www.lufthansa.com/de/en/carry-on-baggage |
| Swiss International Air Lines | 40 | 30 | 10 | n | 55 | 40 | 23 | https://www.swiss.com/ca/en/prepare/baggage/hand-baggage.html |
| Ryanair | 42 | 30 | 20 | y | 55 | 40 | 20 | https://corporate.ryanair.com/news/new-bag-policy-from-november-will-cut-check-bag-fees-reduce-boarding-delays/ |
| British Airways | 40 | 30 | 15 | n | 56 | 45 | 25 | https://www.britishairways.com/en-es/information/baggage-essentials/hand-baggage-allowances |
| Air France | 40 | 30 | 15 | n | 55 | 35 | 25 | https://www.airfrance.us/US/en/common/guidevoyageur/pratique/bagages-cabine-airfrance.htm |
| KLM | 40 | 30 | 15 | n | 55 | 35 | 25 | https://www.klm.com/travel/us_en/prepare_for_travel/baggage/baggage_allowance/index.htm |
| easyJet | 45 | 36 | 20 | y | 56 | 45 | 25 | http://www.easyjet.com/en/help/baggage/cabin-bag-and-hold-luggage |
| Turkish Airlines | unknown |  |  | y | 55 | 40 | 23 | https://www.turkishairlines.com/en-us/any-questions/carry-on-baggage/index.html |
| Aeroflot | must not exceed 80 cm |  |  | n | 55 | 40 | 20 | https://www.aeroflot.ru/us-en/information/preparation/luggage |
| SAS | 40 | 30 | 15 | n | 55 | 40 | 23 | https://www.flysas.com/us-en/travel-info/baggage/ |
| Norwegian | 33 | 25 | 20 | n | 55 | 40 | 23 | https://www.norwegian.com/en/travel-info/baggage/hand-baggage/ |
| Wizz Air | 40 | 30 | 18 | n | 55 | 40 | 23 | https://wizzair.com/en-gb/information-and-services/travel-information/baggage |
| Alitalia | unknown |  |  | y | 55 | 35 | 25 | https://www.alitalia.com/en_us/fly-alitalia/baggage/hand-baggage.html |
| American Airlines | 45 | 35 | 20 | n | 56 | 36 | 23 | https://www.aa.com/i18n/travel-info/baggage/carry-on-baggage.jsp |
| Delta Air Lines | unknown |  |  | n | 56 | 36 | 23 | https://www.delta.com/content/www/en_US/traveling-with-us/baggage/during-your-trip/carry-on.html |
| Southwest Airlines | 47 | 34.3 | 21.6 | n | 61 | 41 | 28 | https://www.southwest.com/html/customer-service/baggage/index.html |
| United | 45 | 27 | 22 | n | 56 | 36 | 23 | https://www.flyertalk.com/forum/united-airlines-mileageplus/1651439-carry-items-meets-united-s-sizer-box-enforcement-7.html |
| Air Canada | 43 | 33 | 16 | n | 55 | 40 | 23 | https://www.aircanada.com/ca/en/aco/home/plan/baggage/carry-on.html |
| Alaska Airlines | unknown |  |  | y | 55 | 36 | 23 | https://www.alaskaair.com/content/travel-info/baggage/carry-on-luggage |
| JetBlue | 43 | 33 | 20 | y | 56 | 36 | 23 | https://www.jetblue.com/at-the-airport/baggage-information |
| Spirit Airlines | 45 | 35 | 20 | y | 56 | 46 | 25 | https://customersupport.spirit.com/hc/en-us/articles/202096476-What-are-the-size-and-weight-limits-for-bags- |
| WestJet | 41 | 33 | 15 | n | 53 | 38 | 23 | https://www.westjet.com/en-ca/travel-info/baggage/carry-on |
| China Southern Airlines | unknown |  |  | n | must not exceed 115 cm |  |  | https://global.csair.com/GB/GB/JTXX/INFO/XLFW/CABA |
| All Nippon Airways | unknown |  |  | y | 55 | 40 | 25 | https://www.ana.co.jp/en/us/international/prepare/baggage/carry-on/carry-rule.html |
| China Eastern Airlines | unknown |  |  | n | must not exceed 158 cm |  |  | https://us.ceair.com/en/content/information/baggage/baggage-allowance |